# Insert text into current buffer from function

Tags: buffer, vim

I'm having a hard time finding the documentation for this. How do I read/write text from the current buffer in my vim functions?

More concretely, if my buffer contains the words `foo bar` how would write a function to overwrite the word `bar` with `cat` so that in the end my buffer contains `foo cat`?

Comment: `:help eval` and `:help functions`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `substitute` ex command inside a function. For example

```
function! ReplaceBar() 
  :%s/bar/cat/g
endfunction
```

This defines a function. The `%` character means operate on the entire buffer. This searches for `bar`, replaces it with `cat`, and the `g` flag replaces every instance on a line, not just the first.

You can run this function by typing `:call ReplaceBar()` and hitting enter. Often it's convenient to define a function that does this kind of work, then define a command that calls it:

```
command! -nargs=0 Bar call ReplaceBar()
```

That command can be run by typing `:Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

To access line(s), you can use the `getline()` function. `setline()` updates those lines in the buffer. Likewise, new lines are inserted via `append()`.

The latter can also be done with `:put ={variable or expression}`, and replacements with `:substitute`. What is better depends on the particular use case. The benefit of the former, lower-level functions is that they don't clobber stuff like the expression register, last used search pattern, search history, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In neovim, they have `nvim_put`. A few examples:

```
:call nvim_put(['cat'], 'c', v:false, v:true) ; insert 'cat' right where the cursor is, as if you typed `:normal! icat`
:call nvim_put(['cat'], 'l', v:true, v:true) ; insert 'cat' on the next line
```

Others have covered the use of `:put` pretty well, so I won't cover it myself.