# How to insert one character into current buffer from a function

Tags: vim

I found how to insert lines into the current buffer from a function:
[Insert text into current buffer from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168253/insert-text-into-current-buffer-from-function)

However, how can I insert **one** character in the current buffer at the cursor location (without inserting a newline as a side effect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing that is by using `normal`:

```
norm!ic
```

The `i` starts insert mode, and you can type what you want after that.